# Loss function for classifying when more than one output can be 1 at a time

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, loss-function

My desired output is not 1-hot encoding, but
like a 10 D vector: `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`
and the input is like the normal MNIST data set.

I want to use TensorFlow to build a model to learn this,
then which loss function should I choose?

Comment: It looks like you are performing [multilabel classfication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification); e.g., if there are potentially multiple digits in one output. If so, use the [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes arre not mutually exlcusive, then you just have multiple sigmoid outputs (instead of softmax function as seen in example MNIST classifiers). Each output will be a separate probability that the network assigns to membership in that class.

For a matching loss function, in TensorFlow, you could use the built-in [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) - note that it works on the logits - the inputs to the sigmoid function - for efficiency. The link explains the maths involved.

You will still want a sigmoid function on the output layer too, for when you read off the predictions, but you apply the loss function above to the *input* of the sigmoid function. Note this is not a requirement of your problem, you can easily write a loss function that works from the sigmoid outputs, just the TensorFlow built-in has been written differently to get a small speed boost.

Comment: I use tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy with_logits ,but my output looks quite bad , nearly all elements in the output is between 0.2-0.4,no higher than 0.5 . the structure of my neural network: output is a set of 64*64*3 channels image , the labels is a set of  4096(64*64) vectors (each element is 0 or 1),the desire output is a set of 4096 vectors..I do
1 convolution layer->max pooling->2 convolution layer ,the activation function is all relu ,and finally a fully connected layer (sigmoid) ...and the output is like I say above....Do you have any ideal or suggestion where I'm wrong? thanks

Comment: @特馒头的馒头 That seems like a different question. I cannot debug your ML problem in comments. If this answer helped at all, then please consider accepting it. If it didn't help, then I am sorry but I cannot go into detail of your whole project. Either way, you will be better off describing your new problem in more detail in a new question.